# D3 force directed uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to generate a D3 force direct graph based on the code [here](http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728). I generated the following script:

```
<script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
    <script>
    var width = 640, height = 480;

var nodes = [{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxxn"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"},{"name": "xxx"}];
var links = [{"source": "0", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "2", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "3", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "4", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "5", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "6", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "7", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "8", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "9", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "10", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "11", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "12", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "13", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "14", "target": "1", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "15", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "16", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "17", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "18", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "19", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "20", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "21", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "22", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "23", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "24", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "25", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "26", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "27", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "28", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "29", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "30", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "31", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "32", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "33", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "34", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "35", "value": 1},{"source": "1", "target": "36", "value": 1}];
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links);

    force.linkDistance(width/2);

    var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
        .data(links)
        .enter().append('line')
        .attr('class', 'link');

    var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'node');

    force.on('end', function() {
        node.attr('r', width/25)
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; });
        link.attr('x1', function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    });    
    force.start();

</script>
```

(the xxxs are actual names).  It is throwing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".  I read in another thread that this can be caused if the nodes are improperly numbered, but I am numbering the nodes from zero and as far as I can tell there are no nodes in links that don't exist in nodes. Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the objects in your `links` array:

```
[{"source": "0", "target": "1", "value": 1},...
//this is a string ---------^
```

You don't have numbers here, just strings. For the force to work, you have to set the **number** of the source and the target.

A simple solution is coercing:

```
links.forEach(function(d) {
    d.source = +d.source;
    d.target = +d.target;
})
```

Here is the resulting code:

```js
var nodes = [{
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxxn"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}, {
  "name": "xxx"
}];
var links = [{
  "source": "0",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "2",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "3",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "4",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "5",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "6",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "7",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "8",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "9",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "10",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "11",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "12",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "13",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "14",
  "target": "1",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "15",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "16",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "17",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "18",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "19",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "20",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "21",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "22",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "23",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "24",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "25",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "26",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "27",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "28",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "29",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "30",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "31",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "32",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "33",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "34",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "35",
  "value": 1
}, {
  "source": "1",
  "target": "36",
  "value": 1
}];
links.forEach(function(d) {
  d.source = +d.source;
  d.target = +d.target;
})
var width = 400,
  height = 400;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links);

force.linkDistance(width / 2);

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
  .data(links)
  .enter().append('line')
  .attr('class', 'link');

var node = svg.selectAll('.node')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('circle')
  .attr('class', 'node');
  
force.on("start", function(){
  svg.append("text")
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", 150)
    .attr("y", 80)
    .text("Calculating...");
});

force.on('end', function() {
  svg.select(".text").remove();
  node.attr('r', width / 25)
    .attr('cx', function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr('cy', function(d) {
      return d.y;
    });
  link.attr('x1', function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr('y2', function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    });

});
force.start();
```

```html
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
```

EDIT: Since you're using `.on("end"` to paint your nodes, you'll have to wait until the force finishes.

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestion.  That makes sense.  I'm generating the script via PHP, so I just got rid of the quotes around the node numbers.  Now when I run it, it throws no errors, but also generates no graph.  Same thing happens when click the "run code snippet" button on this page.  Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @Steve If you look again, you'll see that the chart is being correctly generated in the snippet: click "run code snippet" and wait a little bit and you'll see. The problem is that you're not moving the nodes at each tick, so you'll have to wait until the force finishes (I just put a "calculating..." while the force is running).